# Hibernate 4 to 5 Upgrade Issues - FK naming Strategy changed

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Hibernate 4 to 5 Upgrade Issues - FK naming changed. H5 -> FK+{hash} while H4 -> FK_+{different_hash}. H5 is not recognizing any H4 FK's and re-creating all - which will not work in Production due to Table sizes. Any points on how to keep H4 FK Naming Strategy in H5? Here's my new config in H5 that kept the Table/Column names from H4:

```
hibernate:
  naming:
    implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
    physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
ddlAuto: update
```

Comment: Using ddl auto creation / update isn't something you should use in a production environment. It is strongly recommended not to do that. Nonetheless if I recall correctly there are some legacy strategies for this.

Comment: Even disabling ddlAuto (to none) does not work. H5 does not recognize existing H4 Foreign Key Constraints (names) and re-creates them. What I need is a way to make H5 recognize existing FK Constraints (put in place by H4). Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Then you haven't disabled it... Also ddlAuto isn't a boot property so I guess doesn't do anything. Disabling ddl creation does exactly that it doesn't creat the DDL anymore. If it still is creating things it isn't disabled. BUt apparently you are relying on this for your production system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImprovedNamingStrategy for Hibernate 5](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate#improvednamingstrategy-for-hibernate-5) with Hibernate 5, If you want to keep Hibernate 4 constraint names.

Please, also read about limitations of this approach
https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate#limitations-of-improvednamingstrategy-for-hibernate-5